# Binding columns in an NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I have two classes: `GHTable` and `GHColumn`. A `GHTable` object has an `NSMutableArray` with `GHColumn` objects. Each `GHColumn` has a `name` property (`NSString`).

I have made an UML diagram to make this more clear. Note that I am **not** using Core Data:

[image: UML]

I want to bind the `columns` property of the `GHTable` object to the columns of an `NSTableView`. I want to bind the titles of the columns of the `NSTableView` to the `name` property of the corresponding `GHColumn`.

My question: is there a way to do this through Cocoa Bindings, and if so: how? Or do I need to manually implement the data source for the `NSTableView`?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an NSArrayController. Bind its `Content Array` binding to the mutable array on your GHTable object.

In the NSTableView, bind `Content` to the NSArrayController's `arrangedObjects` contoller key.

In the NSTableView's column, bind Value to the NSArrayController's `arrangedObjects` controller key with the model key path `name`.

If the inspector window shows "Scroll View Bindings" as its title when you click the table view, click it again on the content area and it should change to "Table View Bindings".

Click again on the table's column to select it and the title should change to "Table Column Bindings".

Comment: I actually want to bind the columns themselves. So if there are 20 GHColumn objects, the table must have 20 columns. :)

Comment: @Radek S: Oh, then you need to implement it yourself.